# Can this if else condition be replaced by any operator or can this be written using less code. if so then how?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Can this if else condition be replaced by any operator or can this be written using less code. If so then how?

```
  if workingPeriod<3 and gender=="male": 
    return f"He is not experienced"        
 elif workingPeriod<3 and gender =="female":
    return f"She is not experienced"        
 elif workingPeriod >=3 and gender =="male":            
   return f"He is experienced"        
 elif workingPeriod >=3 and gender =="female":            
   return f"She is experienced"        
 else:   
     pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two conditions (male or female and experienced or not).  You are trying to resolve all combinations of conditions in the same block of if statements and therefore have 4 branches because there are 4 combinations.

Instead of 4 branches you can simplify to resolving each condition separately.  That way you reduce the complexity and the lines of code.

```
prefix = "He" if gender == "male" else "She"
return prefix + (" is experienced" if workingPeriod > 3 else " is not experienced")
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have no other genders than `'male'` or `'female'` (and don't want to return `None` if that *isn't* the case):

```
return f'{"He" if gender=="male" else "She"} is {"not " if workingPeriod<3 else ""}experienced'
```

In case you do have more genders (i.e. the `pass` case`):

```
return f'{"He" if gender=="male" else "She" if gender=="female" else "They"} is {"not " if workingPeriod<3 else ""}experienced'
```